# hasClass() function not working as intended in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is trying to make a slider, that has 2 classes, 'motion1' and 'motion2'. Based on each class, I am trying to apply the transition to each slide at a different time. However, the hasClass function is not detecting the parent with the above class name. Please find the codes here below

```js
$(function(){
  
 let motion1 = $('.motion1');
 let motion2 = $('.motion2');
 let images = $('.column1 img');
 
 images.each(function(){
   if($(this).parents().hasClass(motion1)){
     console.log('hi');
   } else{
     console.log('no');
   }
 });
});
```

```css
#main__slider{
  width:40rem;
  height:25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.column1{
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main__slider">
  <div class="column1 motion1">
    <img src="https://www.arup.com/-/media/arup/images/perspectives/themes/cities/cities-alive/cities-alive-header.jpg?h=1125&la=en&w=2000&hash=415B3F648DFB5F1822DD43328B988A2C78318E7F" alt="">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" alt="">
    <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2018/03/Pomeranian_01.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--vHt6tbFa--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/xjmx1csashjww8j8jwyh.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.drdavidludwig.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-RIS_6IbCLYv1X3bzYW1lmA.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.railengineer.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/AT300_HULL-TRAINS_with-logo.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/content/img/product/large/steam-train-trip-17104839.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1 motion2">
    <img src="https://www.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/topic_centers/977-When_do_girls_stop_growing-732x549-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.askmen.com/1080x540/2018/09/06-125712-how_to_talk_to_girls_on_tinder.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.familyeducation.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/baby%20girl%20names%20image.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn2.momjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Learning-Activities.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1 motion1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg/1200px-Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://expo.advance.net/img/9c4d2bc2c7/width960/30gallery_state_indiv_gym_.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/call_to_action/9127/0843/_7006687_large.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/4pOVrNf6Ezmge6_VKHgYmAyCNoU=/0x0:3642x2712/1200x800/filters:focal(1275x341:1857x923)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/54106607/usa_today_9864342.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can also help me with the code problem. I would also like to ask for your help in achieving the slide function. Here, the images with motion1 and motion2 need to be fadeIn and fadeOut at different time intervals from each other. If it reaches the last slide, the first slide needs to come

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you're passing in a jQuery object, whereas `.hasClass` checks a *string* for whether it's the name of a class

Comment: hasClass function should contain the right param, it's string not jquery object. `if($(this).parents().hasClass('motion1'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) takes a single string argument as a parameter which represents the CSS class you want to check. If we look at your code, we can see that you aren't passing in a string to the `hasClass` function but a jQuery object instead:

```
$(function(){

 let motion1 = $('.motion1');//jQuery Object 
 let motion2 = $('.motion2');//jQuery Object
 let images = $('.column1 img');

 images.each(function(){
   if($(this).parents().hasClass(motion1)){//Bad argument - jQuery Object
     console.log('hi');
   } else{
     console.log('no');
   }
 });
});
```

To fix this, simply pass in the class directly to the `hasClass` method:

```
$(function(){
 let images = $('.column1 img');

 images.each(function(){
   if($(this).parents().hasClass('motion1')){//correct argument - string
     console.log('hi');
   } else{
     console.log('no');
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  
 let motion1 = $('.motion1');
 let motion2 = $('.motion2');
 let images = $('.column1 img');
 
 images.each(function(){
   if($(this).parents().hasClass('motion1')){
     console.log('hi');
   } else{
     console.log('no');
   }
 });
});
```

```css
#main__slider{
  width:40rem;
  height:25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.column1{
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main__slider">
  <div class="column1 motion1">
    <img src="https://www.arup.com/-/media/arup/images/perspectives/themes/cities/cities-alive/cities-alive-header.jpg?h=1125&la=en&w=2000&hash=415B3F648DFB5F1822DD43328B988A2C78318E7F" alt="">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" alt="">
    <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2018/03/Pomeranian_01.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--vHt6tbFa--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/xjmx1csashjww8j8jwyh.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.drdavidludwig.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-RIS_6IbCLYv1X3bzYW1lmA.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.railengineer.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/AT300_HULL-TRAINS_with-logo.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/content/img/product/large/steam-train-trip-17104839.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1 motion2">
    <img src="https://www.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/topic_centers/977-When_do_girls_stop_growing-732x549-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.askmen.com/1080x540/2018/09/06-125712-how_to_talk_to_girls_on_tinder.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.familyeducation.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/baby%20girl%20names%20image.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn2.momjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Learning-Activities.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1 motion1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg/1200px-Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://expo.advance.net/img/9c4d2bc2c7/width960/30gallery_state_indiv_gym_.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/call_to_action/9127/0843/_7006687_large.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/4pOVrNf6Ezmge6_VKHgYmAyCNoU=/0x0:3642x2712/1200x800/filters:focal(1275x341:1857x923)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/54106607/usa_today_9864342.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```